# Only first row works for amount function

Tags: jquery, function

My `sun` function works only for the first row's inputs. How to make it work independently for every row in the table?

[image: inventory Table rows]

```html
<script>
$(function() {
  $("#num1, #num2, #num3",).on("keydown keyup", sum);
  function sum() {
    $("#sum").val(Number($("#num1").val()) * Number($("#num2").val()) );
    $("#sum1").val(Number($("#sum").val()) - (Number($("#sum").val()) * (Number($("#num3").val()) / 100 )));
  }
});
</script>
```

Comment: Please add some details in your post, also some more code snippets. what exactly are you trying to achieve and what ways are not working for you.

Comment: Do you have mind in right place. Provide the details  what you want to do and fields detailds with their ids

Comment: IDs must be unique. Use classes instead. And delegate from a parent wrapper.

Comment: @Ramisha, amount field is auto calculated when user inputs quantity and amount, but it only works for the first row.

Comment: @Bahubali please i have a jquery function that auto sums the amount when user enters quantity and unit cost. This only works for the first row only.

Comment: @Roko,please give me a sample of how to delegate the parent wrapper, I have changed the ids to classes, it still works only for the first row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use classes (instead of unique IDs), and use references to the parent row like `$row.find(".num1")` or `$(".num1", $row)`:

```js
jQuery($ => { // DOM ready and $ alias in scope

  function sum() {
    const $row = $(this).closest("tr");
    
    const $num1 = $row.find(".num1");
    const $num2 = $row.find(".num2");
    const $num3 = $row.find(".num3");
    
    const $sum = $row.find(".sum");
    const $sum1 = $row.find(".sum1");
    
    $sum.val(Number($num1.val()) * Number($num2.val()));
    $sum1.val(Number($sum.val()) - (Number($sum.val()) * Number($num3.val()) / 100));
  }

  $(".myTable").on("input", ".num1, .num2, .num3", sum);

});
```

and use the `"input"` event instead of `"key*"`